# zoom two dimentional array C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, type-2-dimension

> Solved here is the code that worked for me

```
for (i = 0; i < nbLine; i++)
    for (k = 0; k < zoom; k++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nbColumn; j++)
            for (l = 0; l < zoom; l++)
            {
                printf("%d ", *(array+ (i*nbColumn) + j));
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

I have a function that output a two dimensional array ([column][line]) and it need to be zoom, in fact it is like going from

`1 2 
 3 4` 
to a

`1 1 2 2 
 3 3 4 4` array when zoom is equal to 2

here is some code :

```
static void output(int* array, int nbColumn, int nbLine, int zoom)
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    for (i = 0; i < nbColumn; i++)
        for (k = 0; k < zoom; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < nbLine; j++)
                for (l = 0; l < zoom; l++)
                {
                    printf("%d ", *(array+ (i*nbColomn) + j));
                }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

when I try this code on a squared array, it works fine, but when using a rectangular one, it fails. I have tried to debug it by replacing the `printf("%d ", *(array + (i*nbColumn) + j));` by  `printf("%d ", (i*nbColumn) + j);` and it gives me this result for a 8 colomns by 5 rows array :

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your input to the function. What is `tableau`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `nbColumn`, `nbLine` and `zoom` is supposed to do? I assume `zoom` is the amount to repeat the number? And does it only need to 'zoom' horizontally? i.e. your example makes it only duplicate them horizontal something you would not expect with 'zooming'

Comment: Also, your posted function doesn't contain `printf("%d ", (i*pVal->ligne) + j);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I've corrected the ` tableau´ by `array´ and inverted the replacing, sorry for those stupid transcription errors.

Comment: @Neijwiert Well it is supposed to duplicate each position of the array zoom time horizontally and this hole duplication zoom time duplicated vertically like zoom in the diagonal

Comment: Do you have the rows and columns the right way round? Perhaps you need `printf("%d ", *(array + (j*nbColumn) + i));`

Comment: If you want to avoid the vertical duplication, just remove the `for (k=0...` loop

Comment: @simonc I want the vertical duplication too

Comment: @IanAbbott yep I've found this, it give me correct when using the line printf("%d", (i*Line)+j) but not the the first one

Comment: @SvenBorden LOL just realized I independantly made the exact same code. Sorry for wrong answer post. But on-topic. How is it not working for you, because if I call it with for example: int *tmp = new int[4]
 {
  1, 2,
  3, 4
 };

 output(tmp, 2, 2, 3); it works as I thought it should work. Oh and I'm using this in Visual Studio that explains the new operator hehe.

Comment: @Neijwiert Could you try using a 2 dimension array, such as int *tmp = new int[3][2]{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}

Answer (score 0):

A working program source is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
  ifstream in("in.in");
  ofstream out("out.out");

int main(void){
  int m[100][100],i,j,l,noLines,noColumns,zoom;
  in>>noLines>>noColumns>>zoom;

  for(i=0;i<noLines;i++){
    for(j=0;j<noColumns;j++){
      in>>m[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < noLines; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < noColumns; j++){
      for (l = 0; l < zoom; l++) {
        out<<m[i][j]<<' ';
      }
    }
      out<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On the input:

```
4 3 2
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

you get the output:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 
4 4 5 5 6 6 
7 7 8 8 1 1 
2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Changing the parameters on the first line of the input (i.e. the bidimensional array width, height and the zoom), changes the output.

Comment: You need to have a separate function for this task called output and the question is tagged as C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I can see that you are zooming only horizontally, since the elements are duplicated horizontally, but the number of rows is left intact. So you do not need vertical zoom and therefore your cycle with k is unuseful. This should work:

```
static void output(int* array, int nbColumn, int nbLine, int zoom)
{
    int i, j, l;
    for (i = 0; i < nbLine; i++)
    {
            for (j = 0; j < nbColumn; j++)
                for (l = 0; l < zoom; l++)
                {
                    printf("%d ", *(array+ (i*nbColomn) + j));
                }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, as far I can see this does not procuce a vertical duplication

Comment: Yes, as your example started from 2 rows and 2 columns and resulted in 2 rows and 4 columns.